# How to migrate the ApplicationDbContext to the existing DbContext in ASP.NET MVC EF code-first project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I followed the [ASP.NET MVC tutorial](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) to build the ASP.NET MVC project with EF code-first. 
I've created the SchoolContext and use EF code-first to create the Database for my current project.

```
 public class SchoolContext:DbContext
{
    public SchoolContext(DbContextOptions<SchoolContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Instructor> Instructors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OfficeAssignment> OfficeAssignments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CourseAssignment> CourseAssignments { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().ToTable("Course");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Enrollment>().ToTable("Enrollment");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().ToTable("Student");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Department>().ToTable("Department");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Instructor>().ToTable("Instructor");
        modelBuilder.Entity<OfficeAssignment>().ToTable("OfficeAssignment");
        modelBuilder.Entity<CourseAssignment>().ToTable("CourseAssignment");

        modelBuilder.Entity<CourseAssignment>()
            .HasKey(c => new { c.CourseID, c.InstructorID });
    }
}
```

Now I want to add the Authorization function to this project using ASP.NET Identity. 
I notice that I have the ApplicationDbContext inside my project, how can I migrate the ApplicationDbContext to my existing SchoolContext? Or I need to create another database for the ApplicationDbContext?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inherit SchoolContext from `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` then add aspnet identity tables to modelBuilder:

```
 public class SchoolContext:IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
 { ...
```

and OnModelCreating method changes like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>()
                       .ToTable("dbo.AspNetUsers");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                      .ToTable("dbo.AspNetUsers");

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>()
                     .ToTable("dbo.AspNetRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>()
                     .ToTable("dbo.AspNetRoles");

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("dbo.AspNetUserClaims");

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("dbo.AspNetUserRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey((IdentityUserRole r) => new { UserId = r.UserId, RoleId = r.RoleId }).ToTable("dbo.AspNetUserRoles");

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("dbo.AspNetUserLogins");
...
```

Then you should replace all ApplicationDbContext  to SchoolContext entire your solution

Comment: Thanks, I Inherit SchoolContext from IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> and just add the base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); into my original code. It works now.

Comment: It's a little old, ,but didn't you also have to change the `Startup.Auth.cs`?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the same connection string to both the dbContext then all tables of both the context will be created in same database.

You can implement authorization on your controllers using [Authorize] attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I prefer to use Mostafa Esmaeili's workaround.